# How to make messages be sent separately with TcpClient

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, xamarin.android, tcpclient

I have two devices (Android, for instance), one is acting as a server and the second as a client.

The application purpose, for instance, is to make both devices (the ambition is more than 2 devices) play a song simultaneously.

When the client enters the room **while the server is already playing** the server sends multiple messages using `TcpClient.Write()` in the following order:

UPDATE_PARTICIPANTS - Sync client names between connected devices and fresh connected client.

PAUSE - Pause the current playing song, irrelevant for the new client, relevant for other connected clients.

PREPARE - Prepare the client's MediaPlayer (retrieve the MP3 file from the server).

SYNC - Seek to the server's location in the file.

The problem is that the client receives all 3 messages in a single Read, therefore handling this message as a single message and causing bugs and ignoring the other messages.

IE:
510|ServerName|ClientName520|http://192.168.1.1:80

Where 510 is the protocol code for UPDATE and 520 is the protocol code for Prepare, '|' is the delimiter, ServerName is the name of the Server client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see any Write method for TcpClient, what library are you using?

Comment: When communication the client should always wait for a response from server before sending a second command.  If you wait then you will get only one response and not have to separate the messages.

Comment: @nalnpir TcpClient.GetStream().Write(), it is NetworkStream.Write(), my mistake.

Comment: @jdweng I don't get it why both messages are sent together in the first place while using different Write invokes.

Comment: Doesn't matter if they are two different write instructions.  A write doesn't wait until a read occurs.   You have to add the read between the two writes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use NetworkStream instead of the standard TcpClient from .NET?